# Custom routing in code ingniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use codeigniter for an ecommerce project I'm working on but I think I need some custom routing and I'm not sure if this is possible. I want to be able to use this url:

http://myecommsite.com/store/mens

By default in CI this would call the mens function in the store class. What I actually want is it to call a generic function in the store class and feed in 'mens' as a paremeter. The reason for this is that this site needs to have a mens,womens and childrens section.

Is this possible?

Also When I get further down the line...i.e

http://myecommsite.com/store/mens/category1/category2

how do I make Ci work with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply  define a custom [**route**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in `application/config/routes.php`

Something like, for your url http://myecommsite.com/store/mens

```
$route['store/(:any)'] = "store/customfunction/$1";
```

This way all requests will be mapped to your "customfunction" method, which takes the parameter "mens"

You might also want to consdere the [**__remap()**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) function, which overrides the methods (as opposed to the routing, which overrides the whole URI) Quoting from the manual:

> If your controller contains a function named __remap(), it will always
>   get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the
>   normal behavior in which the URI determines which function is called,
>   allowing you to define your own function routing rules.

So you can use a __remap() function in your controller store, and anything will be redirected to that. Any segments after the method name are passed into __remap() as second parameter, and you can use this array with [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).
This could come in handy for your second examples of URI. Might be something like

```
function __remap('mymethod',$array = array())
{
  return call_user_func_array('mymethod',$array);
}
```

and in your method "mymethod" you pick the array element and do what you need to do