# User-friendly URLs instead of Query Strings?

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using seo user friendly in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444151/using-seo-user-friendly-in-php)
>   [Custom routing in code ingniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692992/custom-routing-in-code-ingniter)

I'm deving a CMS and I wanna use User-friendly URLs instead of Query Strings.

e.g.:

`mysite.com/cat_1 => mysite.com/cat_1/itme_1`

instead of

`mysite.com/?cat=1 => mysite.com/?item=1`

How should I implement this? any standard way?

My idea is to use of semi-dynamic pages and generating static snapshots with user-friendly URLS of dynamic pages that use query strings.

Comment: @MikeBrown - not exactly... he doesn't need routing, just basic URL rewriting.

Comment: @jeroen - Again, not a duplicate.  That's another example of routing.  This is URL rewriting, no PHP involved.

Comment: @TheSmose I would agree but I think if he's writing a CMS he wants to use routing rather than requiring the CMS admin to edit .htaccess or muck with mod_rewrite to add a new path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accomplished through the use of .htaccess to modify how the URL is sent to the client. Or as other people say, to prettify the URL. Here are some links to articles to help you get started with the `mod_rewrite` rules required to make this function.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

http://www.roscripts.com/Pretty_URLs_-_a_guide_to_URL_rewriting-168.html

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `.htaccess` to rewrite your URLs internally and route them appropriately to your application.

Here's a specific `.htaccess` example that will do what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cat_([0-9]*) /?cat=$1 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^item_([0-9]*) /?item=$1 [N,QSA]
```

Just put the above in a file called `.htaccess` in your root web folder, and you'll be good to go.

Note that you may have to enable `mod-rewrite` in your apache server if it's not already enabled (most shared hosting providers have it enabled)

Answer (score 1):

This functionality cannot be implemented using only PHP. You need to configure URL rewriting for your HTTP server, which will transform the user-friendly URLs into query strings which your scripts can understand. In the case of Apache, you should look into `mod_rewrite`, which can usually be configured through `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a framework like Codeigniter: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

And review: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

You will need to activate the `mod_rewrite` and create the file `.htaccess`

.htaccess with Codeigniter:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

Then you can use:

```
example.com/class/function/ID
```

I hope that is helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

use asp.net mvc you get it for free ;) but in all seriousness I think PHP has a web engine ([code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692992/custom-routing-in-code-ingniter))that provides advanced routing too. Also, you can role your own using some [Apache black magic](http://www.codinginsight.com/custom-routing-in-php/)

Comment: I think OP is asking for PHP solution (as he tagged `php`)

Comment: I know hence the wink and the segue "but in all seriousness"