# How to use parameters when file php extension is removed?

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite, parameters

Instead of

http://example.com/file.php?color=red
I would like to use

http://example.com/file/red

I have removed my file extensions by adding the code below to .htaccess which will display the content of the http://example.com/file.php on the server when accessing http://example.com/file/

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Now I am looking for a way to pass the "red" parameter to the file when putting this address in the web browser like this http://example.com/file/red

Thanks!

EDIT:
I got the answer to look for something called friendly URLs and that helped me.

I ended up with replacing the first code with this.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/file.php?id=xxx" to "/file/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?color=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /file/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/file/xxx" to "/file.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^file/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ file.php?color=$1 [L]
```

Then with PHP I will just request the parameter like this.

```
$color = $_GET['color'];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User-friendly URLs instead of Query Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715381/user-friendly-urls-instead-of-query-strings)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know it was called friendly URLs. The one you linked to had only broken links, but I found some other guides which finally helped me thanks to the phrase friendly URLs. I will update the question.